# Visual noise in new COD MW

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

[image: MW]

How to fix this visual noise on weapon in new COD MW BETA?

Comment: Have you tried the basics like adjust various settings, install the latest graphics drivers for your GPU, uninstall and reinstall? What _have_ you tried so far? It helps to let us know.

Comment: I've updated nvidia drivers, didn't help. I tried to put off and put on some setting too, no effect.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like low-sample-rate ray tracing/global illumination artifacts.

Comment: First off, this has been a bug only with the BETA; the released game does not have the problem. There is a [fix](https://www.dexerto.com/call-of-duty/how-to-fix-blur-depth-of-field-grain-weapons-modern-warfare-beta-1051988)  only for PC players, though. Therefore I am not posting this as an answer, since the beta has been concluded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It refers to the version of a game that cannot be installed/played anymore.

Comment: @DrFish As per [this thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14661/dealing-with-old-questions-about-non-existent-features) I suggest leaving it open.

Answer (score 1):

Goto nvidia control panel change 3D image with preview to "Let the application decide" and then apply then in game turn AA to filmic SMAA x2 and filmic strength max should remove it hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what platform you're on, but this was an issue I had on Xbox. I figured it had something to do with the game's motion blur, but after disabling the motion blur settings for both the game and the guns, I still had the visual noise. I'm assuming that this has something to do with the smaller beta download, and I've seen visual noise be an issue on betas in the past, most recently with Battlefield V's beta on Xbox. Battlefield V then released with much less visual noise in the final product, so my assumption is this won't be an issue when the game launches.